# Cuando pongo una imagen de fondo estatica solo se ve estatica cuando hago scroll desde mi ordenador

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid-layout

Intento poner una imagen de fondo en mi proyecto web y cuando haga scrollla imagen quede fija mientras el contenido se mueve. Cuando abro la web desde el ordenador funciona bien pero al subirla a github para ver como queda desde mi dispositivo movil veo que la imagen se queda pegada con el contenido. asi tengo puesta la imagen:

```
`  body {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
background-image: url("img/luna.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center center;
}`
```

Comment: Buen día, necesitamos reproducir tu problema para así poder identificar con mayor facilidad el problema. ¿Podrías adjuntar también tu HTML?...

Comment: No se si será el caso pero si no recuerdo mal el atachmet fixed no se aplica en iOs. ¿Es tu caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es probable que la propiedad `background-attachment: fixed` no funcione en ciertos dispositivos móviles. Una posibilidad que tienes está en crear una capa fijada arriba, con el ancho y el alto de la ventana e incluyendo la imagen de fondo:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.background {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/02/14/18/55/flowers-7790227_1280.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Empieza tu contenido -->
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus leo sem, ullamcorper id velit at, tincidunt ultricies elit. Aliquam finibus efficitur enim, sit amet maximus nulla imperdiet ultricies. Quisque iaculis magna sed turpis elementum tincidunt. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Cras consectetur dignissim luctus. Maecenas vitae diam sollicitudin, tincidunt purus non, scelerisque arcu. Sed scelerisque ante eu erat lobortis, vel posuere ex semper. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur blandit faucibus sapien ut dignissim. In varius ac nunc sed pellentesque. Fusce vulputate felis eget arcu vulputate, vel tempus dolor vehicula. Proin posuere molestie interdum. Aenean nunc purus, luctus a magna quis, varius sollicitudin neque. Pellentesque vitae diam non nisi vehicula auctor. Suspendisse nibh magna, tincidunt eu pellentesque a, efficitur quis libero.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse mattis sem sit amet leo facilisis, molestie sollicitudin nulla pharetra. Morbi ornare aliquet sodales. Pellentesque sodales enim lacinia turpis mollis, non pellentesque lacus feugiat. Cras sodales justo et ex eleifend, id tincidunt lacus pulvinar. Sed posuere consectetur blandit. Proin venenatis tellus arcu, eu faucibus sapien fermentum sit amet. Mauris molestie turpis sed ex interdum ornare. Nulla vehicula diam eu sollicitudin efficitur. Nunc lacinia, eros convallis tincidunt finibus, augue ante ornare lorem, ac semper nibh nibh non ex. Quisque nec eleifend purus.</p>
  <!-- Acaba tu contenido -->
  <div class="background"></div>
</body>
```